# Return the result from inner join linq from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'm trying to return this data from a linq to my view, but I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Please help

My Controller
[image]

My View
[image]

Error Message
[image]

Comment: Do not post images of code. Post the actual code with proper formatting

Comment: ok, sorry for this

Comment: i suggest you edit the question and replace the image with the relevant code. Make sure to properly format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use anonymous object as the view model for your strongly typed view.

You should create a view model with those 3 properties and use that in your LINQ projection part.

```
public class CustomerCity
{
   public int Id { set; get;}
   public string Ruc { set; get;}
   public string City { set; get;}
}
```

Now in your LINQ query, instead of projecting to an anonymous object, project to `CustomerCity` object.

```
select new CustomerCity { 
                            Id = cus.Id, 
                            Ruc=cus.ruc, 
                            City=muni.desc_city 
                        }
```

Now your view should be strongly typed to a collection of this view model objects

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerCity>
<table class="table">
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
       <td>@item.Id</td>
       <td>@item.Ruc</td>
       <td>@item.City</td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but I tried this and got this message:

 The entity or complex type 'WebBPO_Soft.Models.customer_city' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

In this case, I can't use an anonymous object?

Comment: Did you follow exactly what is in the answer ? Creating a new view model class and **using that** in your LINQ projection part ?

Comment: yes friend, I created a new class with the properties I need.

        public ActionResult Clientes()
        {
            var customers = (from cus in db.T_Customer
                             join muni in db.T_City on cus.cus_dir1 equals muni.id
                             select new customer_city { id = cus.id, municipio = cus.ruc }).ToList();

            return View(customers);
        }

Comment: The error you are getting usually happens when you try to use an entity class( which is being used in your DbContext class ) in your LINQ projection statement. Do you have such a scenario. The class should be a just a view model which you use only in that LINQ projection part and in your view. Not in your DbContext class